# How do I get printf-like warnings with variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, variadic-functions, gcc-warning

If I compile g++ with -Wformat on the following code, I get a warning, as expected.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("argc %lld\n", argc);
}
```

However, if compile the following code, I get no warning.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(char const * s, Ts && ... ts)
{
    printf(s, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    foo("argc %lld\n", argc);
}
```

I was a bit surprised, but I thought maybe the references were throwing off the detection, so I tried this.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(char const * s, Ts ... ts)
{
    printf(s, ts...);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    foo("argc %lld\n", argc);
}
```

However, even with that, I get no warning.  Hmmm.

Since I'm compiling with C++17, I tried this.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
[[gnu::format(printf, 1, 2)]]
void foo(char const * s, Ts ... ts)
{
    printf(s, ts...);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    foo("bar %lld\n", argc);
    printf("bar %lld\n", argc);
}
```

I still get no warning, but I do get a nice error...

```
error: 'format' attribute argument 3 value '2' does not refer to a variable argument list
```

OK, I get it, but if I have to change to a variable argument list, then I lose the type information.

---

The real issue is that I have a function kinda like this...

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... ArgTs>
void format(T t, char const * format_str, ArgTs && ... args);
```

In that function, I do some stuff with T and ArgTs, but I want the same printf style warnings I would get if I were to call printf with the format_str and args.  I need the type information provided by the arguments, so I can't just use a variable argument list.

Of course, I can write an empty function that takes a variable argument list, and annotate it with [[gnu::format]], but that behaves the exact same way as calling printf() above, so it only works if called directly with a variable argument list, and does not work if called with a variadic argument pack expansion.

So, how do I get the benefit of `[[gnu::format]]` with a function that does not take its arguments by variable argument list?

I could use a macro, of course, and have it call a do-nothing function with the `[[gnu::format]]` attribute, then call the real one, but I don't want to use a macro for this.

Comment: If you can use C++20, there is `std::print` and `std::format` which give you printf like syntax with C++ variadic templates and type safety for printing and string creation respectively.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Th36nPnq9

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aq5KndYd8

Comment: So, with the godblot links above, it is of course now clear that it has to do with the visibility of the format string argument.

The second requires a char * template, but the first takes a lambda with the value.  Made me think the compiler may be able to see through this: https://godbolt.org/z/7a5jr5MMn but that does not work.

The lambda solution seems workable.

Comment: Sadly, I'm constrained to C++17.

Comment: Then use this library : https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Comment: Yeah - we already have a logging library that uses the printf style and it is used all over the place.  I don't want to rewrite the thing - I just want to add the ability to warn for misuse.  Fortunately (or not, depending on your perspective), most things use some logging macros - so I was able to get the lambda work-around going.

Comment: Clang seems to work properly using `[[gnu::format(printf, 1, 2)]]`.

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani Indeed! ... and it even tells the user about the diff between gcc and clang: _"warning: GCC requires a function with the 'format' attribute to be variadic [-Wgcc-compat]"_ ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TnfTxbxzj))